# How to find $[T]_{\alpha}^{\alpha}$ for linear map $T: M_{2\times 2} \rightarrow M_{2\times 2}$ defined by $T(x) = Bx$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, linear-transformations

I am asked to find $[T]_{\alpha}^{\alpha}$ for linear map $T: M_{2\times 2} \rightarrow M_{2\times 2}$ where $\alpha$ is the standard basis and

$T(x) = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1 \\
    0 & -1 
\end{bmatrix}
 x$

How can I approach this... I tried applying T to every vector in the standard basis and then decomposing the result in terms of the standard basis, but this yields a $4\times 4$ matrix and I am totally lost.

Any help?

Comment: You should indeed be getting a $4 \times 4$ matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Hint :-

First of all since $M_{2\times 2}$ is $4$ dimensional hence the matrix for $T$ must be a $4\times 4$ matrix. So if we denote by $E_{ij}$ the basis of $M_{2\times 2}$, where $E_{ij}$ is $2\times 2 $ matrix having $1$ as the $ij$-th entry and the rest of the entry is $0$, then

$T(E_{11})$ = $\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1 \\
    0 & -1 
\end{bmatrix}$.$\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}$ = $\begin{bmatrix}
                   1 & 0\\
                   0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}  $ = $1.E_{11}+0.E_{12}+0.E_{21}+0.E_{22}$ and hence the first column of the matrix of $T$ contains $1,0,0,0$ in that order from top to bottom.

Similarly, find $T(E_{12})$, etc., write it as a linear combination of $E_{ij}$'s and write the matrix of $T$.

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$
T\pmatrix{a&b\\c&d} = \pmatrix{a+c&b+d\\-c&-d}
$$
Correspondingly, the matrix of $T$ with respect to the standard basis is given by
$$
[T]_\alpha^\alpha = \pmatrix{
1&0&1&0\\
0&1&0&1\\
0&0&-1&0\\
0&0&0&-1}
$$